how to loop through dictionary and store certain values for later use
I have this dictionary created by output from a test device:
    "device_IPs": [
        {
            "INTERFACE": "Vlan300",
            "IP_ADDRESS": "3.3.3.1",
            "PROTO": "down",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "INTERFACE": "Vlan400",
            "IP_ADDRESS": "4.4.4.1",
            "PROTO": "down",
            "STATUS": "up"
        }
    ]
}

Basically i want to write a playbook that uses all of the INTERFACE values for another task - the task applies config to those vlan interfaces (derived from the INTERFACE value in the dict)
This is my playbook:

---
- name: run command and parse with textFSM
  hosts: switches
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: show command and store in var
    cisco.ios.ios_command:
      commands: show ip interface brief | e una|Eth
    register: sh_ip_int_br_output

  - name: parse output data
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      device_IPs: "{{ sh_ip_int_br_output.stdout[0] | parse_cli_textfsm('testFSM_templates/ios_show_ip_int_br.textfsm') }}"


  
  - name: add ip helper to vlan 
    cisco.ios.ios_config:
      lines:
        - ip helper-address 1.1.1.1
      parents: "interface {{ each one of the INTERFACE values from dict }}"

How do I loop through each 'INTERFACE' key in the dictionary above, store the 'INTERFACE' value in a variable and loop through that later on in the last task ?
Hope that makes sense, Thanks
EDIT - this has been solved thanks to larsks & Vladimir's help
I added the following to my playbook
  - name: extract data from dictionary list
    set_fact:
      dict_interface_info: "{{ device_IPs | map (attribute='INTERFACE') }}"


  - name: add ip helper
    cisco.ios.ios_config:
      lines:
        - ip helper-address 1.1.1.1
      parents: "interface {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ dict_interface_info }}"



Loops

What do you mean by each one of the INTERFACE values from dict? There are two dictionaries in the list.

Don't think about loops; think about filters. The map filter can be used to extract a particular attribute from a list of dictionaries, and we can use set_fact to dynamically define new variables in a playbook:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    device_IPs: [
        {
            "INTERFACE": "Vlan300",
            "IP_ADDRESS": "3.3.3.1",
            "PROTO": "down",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "INTERFACE": "Vlan400",
            "IP_ADDRESS": "4.4.4.1",
            "PROTO": "down",
            "STATUS": "up"
        }
      ]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        interfaces: "{{ device_IPs | map(attribute='INTERFACE') }}"

    - debug:
        var: interfaces

Running this produces as output:
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "interfaces": [
        "Vlan300",
        "Vlan400"
    ]
}


Hi Larsks, thank you very much you were a big help :) , the map filter is perfect for this
I have now modified my playbook and it works exactly how I want it to

Q: "Loop through each 'INTERFACE' key in the dictionary."
A: Create a list of the interfaces. For example, you can put this declaration into the vars
  interfaces: "{{ device_IPs | map(attribute='INTERFACE') }}"

gives
  interfaces: [Vlan300, Vlan400]

Create a dictionary of the devices
  device_dict: "{{ dict(interfaces|zip(device_IPs)) }}"

gives
  device_dict:
    Vlan300: {INTERFACE: Vlan300, IP_ADDRESS: 3.3.3.1, PROTO: down, STATUS: up}
    Vlan400: {INTERFACE: Vlan400, IP_ADDRESS: 4.4.4.1, PROTO: down, STATUS: up}

Now, you can easily iterate whatever you want. For example,
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ device_dict[item].IP_ADDRESS }}
          {{ device_dict[item].PROTO }}
          {{ device_dict[item].STATUS }}
      loop: "{{ interfaces }}"

gives
ok: [switch_01] => (item=Vlan300) => 
  msg: 3.3.3.1 down up
ok: [switch_01] => (item=Vlan400) => 
  msg: 4.4.4.1 down up



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: switches

  vars:

    device_IPs:
      - {INTERFACE: Vlan300, IP_ADDRESS: 3.3.3.1, PROTO: down, STATUS: up}
      - {INTERFACE: Vlan400, IP_ADDRESS: 4.4.4.1, PROTO: down, STATUS: up}

    interfaces: "{{ device_IPs | map(attribute='INTERFACE') }}"
    device_dict: "{{ dict(interfaces|zip(device_IPs)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: interfaces | to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: device_dict | to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ device_dict[item].IP_ADDRESS }}
          {{ device_dict[item].PROTO }}
          {{ device_dict[item].STATUS }}
      loop: "{{ interfaces }}"



Hi Vladimir, thank you very much Your example with looping through the list of interfaces (derived from the KEY : Values in the original dict) and then using the 'item' has helped he to solve this Big thanks :)
